# Auto running from a USB drive on a windows device

Tags: c, python-3.x, windows, usb, autorun

I need to run my code from a USB, without python or the necessary packages for it to work. Perhaps a C file to install the necessary things onto the computer, or the necessary files on the USB. But i'm not sure how to go about this. It needs to autorun the file,, as soon as its plugged in.

Comment: C program is a really poor choice for an installer.

Comment: I don't think this is possible for obvious reasons. It was possible on Windows XP and after is has been misused as a virus propagation vector, Microsoft has removed it with one of the service packs.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Really? Wasn't aware of it. Good to know. Well, one can use a bootable USB :)

Comment: @EugeneSh. Bootable USB? Could you provide documentation to that? One that could run a exe on plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Autorun has been severely crippled in recent years, especially USB sticks. For the exact same reason you want to use it, it is simply too easy to walk up to a machine and plug in a USB stick when nobody is looking and automatically install some kind of malware. Unpatched Windows XP was probably the last time autorun worked "properly".

You may still add the [autorun.inf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/autorun-cmds) entries to display your additional commands in the context menu but this will require user interaction.